# Need to match elements from different nodes

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

Below is a snippet of the XML.

```
<wd:Report_Data xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday.report/CRINT-Outbound">
    <wd:Report_Entry>
        <wd:Worker>
            <wd:Employee_ID>TestId1</wd:Employee_ID>
            <wd:Full_Legal_Name>Test Name1</wd:Full_Legal_Name>
        </wd:Worker>
        <wd:Deduction-Code>TestCode1</wd:Deduction-Code>
        <wd:Result_Line_Amount>100</wd:Result_Line_Amount>
    </wd:Report_Entry>
    <wd:Report_Entry>
        <wd:Worker>
            <wd:Employee_ID>TestId1</wd:Employee_ID>
            <wd:Full_Legal_Name>Test Name1</wd:Full_Legal_Name>
        </wd:Worker>
        <wd:Earning_Code>TestCode1</wd:Earning_Code>
        <wd:Result_Line_Amount>200</wd:Result_Line_Amount>
    </wd:Report_Entry>
</wd:Report_Data>
```

Below is a snippet of my XSLT.

```
    <xsl:variable name="employeeId">
        <xsl:value-of select="wd:Worker/wd:Employee_ID"/>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:variable name="deductionCode">
        <xsl:value-of select="wd:Earning_Code"/>
    </xsl:variable>

    <OffsetAmount>
        <xsl:variable name="offsetCode" select="$deductionCode"/>

        <xsl:apply-templates select="/wd:Report_Data/wd:Report_Entry[wd:Deduction-Code]">
            <xsl:with-param name="idParam" select="$employeeId"></xsl:with-param>
            <xsl:with-param name="deductionParam" select="$offsetCode"></xsl:with-param>
        </xsl:apply-templates>

    </OffsetAmount>

</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/wd:Report_Data/wd:Report_Entry[wd:Deduction-Code]">
    <xsl:param name="idParam"/>
    <xsl:param name="deductionParam"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="/wd:Report_Data/wd:Report_Entry[wd:Worker/wd:Employee_ID = $idParam and wd:Deduction-Code = $deductionParam]/wd:Result_Line_Amount"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I need to match the wd:Deduction-Code from one node to the matching wd:Earning_Code from another node so I can include the corresponding amounts for earning and deduction in the output like below.

```
TestId1, Test Name1, TestCode1, 100, 200
```

But with my code, I am able to get TestId1, Test Name1, TestCode1, 100 but not 200.

```
TestId1, Test Name1, TestCode1, 100,
```

Any suggestion would be most welcome. Thanks!

Comment: I am not sure I understand. So, for each `wd:Employee_ID` you need to find two `wd:Report_Entry` elements, one containing `wd:Deduction-Code` and the other containing `wd:Earning_Code` where those codes are equal and then output both `wd:Result_Line_Amount` elements?

Comment: Also, your namespace prefix `wd:` does not have a definition, which makes your XML input a malformed document.

Comment: The answer is YES to your first comment. I need to get both wd:Result_Line_Amount from earning and deduction.

As for the namespace, I have it in my code, I just removed it from the snippet. Sorry if it caused confusion.

Comment: No, you misunderstood me I'm afraid. If there are namespace prefixes, there _must_ be a definition for them in your input XML. What identifies a `wd:Report_Entry` element? The Employee ID or the Codes?

Comment: Sorry I'm quite new to XSLT. I only have namespace for the wd:Report_Data.  I have updated it in the original post.
As for the wd:Report_Entry, it will contain wd:Worker/wd:Employee_ID, wd:Worker/wd:Full_Legal_Name, wd:Result_Line_Amount, and either wd:Deduction-Code OR wd:Earning_Code.

Hope this helps clarify my issue. Thanks @MathiasMüller!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look for all `wd:Report_Entry` elements with an `wd:Deduction-Code` element:

```
<xsl:for-each select="wd:Report_Entry[wd:Deduction-Code]">
```

Then, output the Employee ID and their full name (represented as `wd:Worker/*`) and the value of the `wd:Deduction-Code` element, separated by whitespaces:

```
<xsl:value-of select="string-join(wd:Worker/*|wd:Deduction-Code,' ')"/>
```

Finally, look for a `wd:Report_Entry` element with an `wd:Earning_Code` element where the two codes correspond and output the `wd:Result_Line_Amount` elements of both:

```
<xsl:value-of select="string-join(wd:Result_Line_Amount|//wd:Report_Entry[wd:Earning_Code = current()/wd:Deduction-Code]/wd:Result_Line_Amount,' ')"/>
```

Important: The stylesheet below assumes that there are only to `wd:Report_Entry` elements that share the same code.

A note on XML design: It is quite cumbersome to have incosistent naming, as in your input XML. There are element names with hyphenated names, but also ones with an underscore.

**Stylesheet**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0"
    xmlns:wd="www.wd.com">
    <xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="/wd:Report_Data">

        <xsl:for-each select="wd:Report_Entry[wd:Deduction-Code]">
            <xsl:value-of select="string-join(wd:Worker/*|wd:Deduction-Code,' ')"/>
            <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="string-join(wd:Result_Line_Amount|//wd:Report_Entry[wd:Earning_Code = current()/wd:Deduction-Code]/wd:Result_Line_Amount,' ')"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

**XML Input**

As I pointed out in the comments, your input XML is malformed if there is no definiton of the namespace prefix `wd:`.

```
<wd:Report_Data xmlns:wd="www.wd.com">
    <wd:Report_Entry>
        <wd:Worker>
            <wd:Employee_ID>TestId1</wd:Employee_ID>
            <wd:Full_Legal_Name>Test Name1</wd:Full_Legal_Name>
        </wd:Worker>
        <wd:Deduction-Code>TestCode1</wd:Deduction-Code>
        <wd:Result_Line_Amount>100</wd:Result_Line_Amount>
    </wd:Report_Entry>
    <wd:Report_Entry>
        <wd:Worker>
            <wd:Employee_ID>TestId1</wd:Employee_ID>
            <wd:Full_Legal_Name>Test Name1</wd:Full_Legal_Name>
        </wd:Worker>
        <wd:Earning_Code>TestCode1</wd:Earning_Code>
        <wd:Result_Line_Amount>200</wd:Result_Line_Amount>
    </wd:Report_Entry>
</wd:Report_Data>
```

**XML Output**

```
TestId1 Test Name1 TestCode1 100 200
```

---

**EDIT**: Another stylesheet version, using template matches:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0"
    xmlns:wd="www.wd.com">
    <xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="wd:Report_Entry[wd:Deduction-Code]">
            <xsl:value-of select="string-join(wd:Worker/*|wd:Deduction-Code,' ')"/>
            <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="string-join(wd:Result_Line_Amount|//wd:Report_Entry[wd:Earning_Code = current()/wd:Deduction-Code]/wd:Result_Line_Amount,' ')"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="text()"/>

</xsl:transform>
```

Comment: I'll try this one. Does this solution have a similar approach using templates instead of for-each so I can try both? Thanks @MathiasMüller!